# Alternative of Raycast for UI Items in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am implementing gazing algorithm for a VR project in Unity3D. So far what I have found out here is using `Physics.Raycast` and adding BoxCollider2D component with every button object to detect whether user is looking at it. I want to avoid using Raycast because it is expensive and may create performance problems as I have very complex UI structure to deal with.

I tried using cursor lock but unfortunately it isn't for mobile platform.

I also tried using center of camera viewport to check if `rect` of button object contains world point created by

`Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,Camera.main.nearClipPlane));`

It works fine when button object's rect transform is anchored as middle-center. But doesnt work when it has some other settings or if button is tilted a bit(in world space canvas). And I am not much familiar with how rect transform works and how to find its exact position in world space.

Does anyone knows the solution? Or is there any other way to do this?

All kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if you are doing oculus or not but this is a good read anyway https://developer.oculus.com/blog/unitys-ui-system-in-vr/

Comment: I have checked sample project from Unity and it is implemented on Event System's BaseRaycaster class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, it was different values in z-axis causing problem. following solution works fine without using `Physics.Raycast`:

```
void Update () 
{
    pos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,Vector3.Distance(transform.position,Camera.main.transform.position)));
    _rect = new Rect(pos.x-size,pos.y-size,size,size);

    _rect2 = new Rect(transform.position.x-rt.rect.width/2,transform.position.y-rt.rect.height/2,rt.rect.width,rt.rect.height);

    Hit = _rect2.Overlaps(_rect);

    if(Hit)
    {
        if (!isEntered)
        {
            _button.OnPointerEnter(new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current));
        }
        isEntered = true;

        timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        if(timeElapsed >= 3) // autoclick after 3 sec.
        {
            timeElapsed = 0;
            _button.onClick.Invoke();
            isEntered = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        timeElapsed = 0;
        if (isEntered)
        {
            _button.OnPointerExit(new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current));
        }
        isEntered = false;

    }
}
```